# Packages vs classes

Tags: oop, plsql

How similar are packages in PL/SQL and the classes in C++ ? I am getting to know about packages for the first time and their arrangement and constitution using procedures and functions reminded me of classes in C++ .But at the same time I guess there are differences between these two .I guess , inability to create objects of packages as we can do in case of class is one of them . I wanted to know what are the similarities and differences between packages and class . Are packages, by any chance meant for replicating object oriented programming in PL/SQL ?

Comment: No. PL/SQL is not an object oriented language. However Oracle SQL does have support for objects. And because one can use (generally speaking ) all SQL-features from PL/SQL one can also use objects in PL/SQL code. Please see e.g. [Database Object-Relational Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/toc.htm) to get you started.

Comment: Packages provide encapsulation and overloading, but otherwise they are more like libraries or Perl modules than C++/Java classes. PL/SQL also has object types that provide inheritance and constructors etc and are a lot closer to the concept of a class.

Comment: PL/SQL packages are comparable to singletons in OOP.